# How could I use my Json object instead a hardcoded object in my IONIC app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework, mobile

This is an example services.js file of an IONIC app that I found. Instead of the hardcoded object (var employees) I want to use a json file. How I can do that. I have an idea below of this code, but it doesn't work. I think this could help a lot of people starting with Ionic.

This is the first services.js code:

```
angular.module('directory.services', [])

.factory('EmployeeService', function($q) {

    var employees = [
        {"id": 1, "firstName": "James", "lastName": "King", "managerId": 0, "managerName": "", "reports": 4, "title": "President and CEO", "department": "Corporate", "cellPhone": "617-000-0001", "officePhone": "781-000-0001", "email": "jking@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "James_King.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakejking", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 2, "firstName": "Julie", "lastName": "Taylor", "managerId": 1, "managerName": "James King", "reports": 2, "title": "VP of Marketing", "department": "Marketing", "cellPhone": "617-000-0002", "officePhone": "781-000-0002", "email": "jtaylor@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "Julie_Taylor.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakejtaylor", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 3, "firstName": "Eugene", "lastName": "Lee", "managerId": 1, "managerName": "James King", "reports": 0, "title": "CFO", "department": "Accounting", "cellPhone": "617-000-0003", "officePhone": "781-000-0003", "email": "elee@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "Eugene_Lee.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakeelee", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 4, "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Williams", "managerId": 1, "managerName": "James King", "reports": 3, "title": "VP of Engineering", "department": "Engineering", "cellPhone": "617-000-0004", "officePhone": "781-000-0004", "email": "jwilliams@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "John_Williams.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakejwilliams", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 5, "firstName": "Ray", "lastName": "Moore", "managerId": 1, "managerName": "James King", "reports": 2, "title": "VP of Sales", "department": "Sales", "cellPhone": "617-000-0005", "officePhone": "781-000-0005", "email": "rmoore@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "Ray_Moore.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakermoore", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 6, "firstName": "Paul", "lastName": "Jones", "managerId": 4, "managerName": "John Williams", "reports": 0, "title": "QA Manager", "department": "Engineering", "cellPhone": "617-000-0006", "officePhone": "781-000-0006", "email": "pjones@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "Paul_Jones.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakepjones", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 7, "firstName": "Paula", "lastName": "Gates", "managerId": 4, "managerName": "John Williams", "reports": 0, "title": "Software Architect", "department": "Engineering", "cellPhone": "617-000-0007", "officePhone": "781-000-0007", "email": "pgates@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "Paula_Gates.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakepgates", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 8, "firstName": "Lisa", "lastName": "Wong", "managerId": 2, "managerName": "Julie Taylor", "reports": 0, "title": "Marketing Manager", "department": "Marketing", "cellPhone": "617-000-0008", "officePhone": "781-000-0008", "email": "lwong@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "Lisa_Wong.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakelwong", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 9, "firstName": "Gary", "lastName": "Donovan", "managerId": 2, "managerName": "Julie Taylor", "reports": 0, "title": "Marketing Manager", "department": "Marketing", "cellPhone": "617-000-0009", "officePhone": "781-000-0009", "email": "gdonovan@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "Gary_Donovan.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakegdonovan", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 10, "firstName": "Kathleen", "lastName": "Byrne", "managerId": 5, "managerName": "Ray Moore", "reports": 0, "title": "Sales Representative", "department": "Sales", "cellPhone": "617-000-0010", "officePhone": "781-000-0010", "email": "kbyrne@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "Kathleen_Byrne.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakekbyrne", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 11, "firstName": "Amy", "lastName": "Jones", "managerId": 5, "managerName": "Ray Moore", "reports": 0, "title": "Sales Representative", "department": "Sales", "cellPhone": "617-000-0011", "officePhone": "781-000-0011", "email": "ajones@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "Amy_Jones.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakeajones", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 12, "firstName": "Steven", "lastName": "Wells", "managerId": 4, "managerName": "John Williams", "reports": 0, "title": "Software Architect", "department": "Engineering", "cellPhone": "617-000-0012", "officePhone": "781-000-0012", "email": "swells@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "Steven_Wells.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakeswells", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"}
    ];

    // We use promises to make this api asynchronous. This is clearly not necessary when using in-memory data
    // but it makes this service more flexible and plug-and-play. For example, you can now easily replace this
    // service with a JSON service that gets its data from a remote server without having to changes anything
    // in the modules invoking the data service since the api is already async.

    return {
        findAll: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(employees);
            return deferred.promise;
        },

        findById: function(employeeId) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var employee = employees[employeeId - 1];
            deferred.resolve(employee);
            return deferred.promise;
        },

        findByName: function(searchKey) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var results = employees.filter(function(element) {
                var fullName = element.firstName + " " + element.lastName;
                return fullName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchKey.toLowerCase()) > -1;
            });
            deferred.resolve(results);
            return deferred.promise;
        },

        findByManager: function (managerId) {
            var deferred = $q.defer(),
                results = employees.filter(function (element) {
                    return parseInt(managerId) === element.managerId;
                });
            deferred.resolve(results);
            return deferred.promise;
        }

    }

});
```

And this is how I tried to use my own json file:

```
angular.module('directory.services', [])

.factory('EmployeeService', function($q,$http) {

    $http.get("http://localhost:3000/api/users").then(function(response){

            myObject = response.data; 


        });

    var employees = myObject;

    // We use promises to make this api asynchronous. This is clearly not necessary when using in-memory data
    // but it makes this service more flexible and plug-and-play. For example, you can now easily replace this
    // service with a JSON service that gets its data from a remote server without having to changes anything
    // in the modules invoking the data service since the api is already async.

    return {
        findAll: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(employees);
            return deferred.promise;
        },

        findById: function(employeeId) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var employee = employees[employeeId - 1];
            deferred.resolve(employee);
            return deferred.promise;
        },

        findByName: function(searchKey) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var results = employees.filter(function(element) {
                var fullName = element.firstName + " " + element.lastName;
                return fullName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchKey.toLowerCase()) > -1;
            });
            deferred.resolve(results);
            return deferred.promise;
        },

        findByManager: function (managerId) {
            var deferred = $q.defer(),
                results = employees.filter(function (element) {
                    return parseInt(managerId) === element.managerId;
                });
            deferred.resolve(results);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: I just solve it by myself  : .factory('FlightService', function($q,$http) {

        function miObjeto(){
            return $http.get("http://localhost:3000/api/flights").then(function(response){

                vuelos = response.data; 
                return  vuelos

            });
            }

        var flights = miObjeto();

Comment: Anytime. Can you accept an answer, or answer your own question below to help others who may have a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any errors in the console? Maybe this helps.

```
$http.get('path/to/api/users.json').success(function (data) {

    var employees = data;
    console.log("success");

})
.error(function () {
    console.log("error getting json");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `EmployeeService` you have a problem with this bit:

```
$http.get("http://localhost:3000/api/users").then(function(response){
    myObject = response.data; 
});
```

The `$http` component doesn't use the promise `.then()`

You need to use something like this

```
$http({
    method: "get",
    url: "some.url.com",
    params: request_data // json object that will become get vars
})
.success(function(data) {
  // result
})
.error(function(data, status) {
  // fail
});
```